# Access to http X_* headers on AWS EB PHP 5.4

Tags: php, wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, wordpress-rest-api

I have the Wordpress deployed to the AWS EB platform PHP 5.4.45. When I make a request from Angular frontend to the API with cookie authorization I need to include `X_WP_NONCE` header, otherwise, Wordpress will ignore my auth cookie.

The problem is that on EB deployment there is no `X_WP_NOCE` in the `$_SERVER` variable. Neither there is `HTTP_X_WP_NONCE`. There is no nonce at all.

And it looks like all headers which prefixed with `X_*` getting stripped out.

```
curl -XGET -H 'A: this works' -H 'X_A: this does not work' http://example.com/

var_dump($_SERVER);

--->

array(76) {
...
["HTTP_A"]=>
  string(19) "this works"
...

// But no HTTP_X_A variable
)
```

Unfortunately, `X_WP_NONCE` is the part of wordpress core and I cannot edit this code.

How can I tell EB to pass `X_*` headers to php?

Thank you,

**UPDATE 1:** apache_request_headers() does see the required header.

Comment: What is the AWS EBT platform? There is no service abbreviated with EBT. Do you mean Elastic Beanstalk?

Comment: @MarkB Elastic Beanstalk, people occasionally call it EBT

Comment: Beanstalk refers to the stalk of a bean plant. If you were going to (incorrectly) split that into two words it would be "Bean Stalk" not "Beans Talk".

Comment: Considering that in a Google search for "AWS EBT", this question is the top result, I think it's pretty safe to conclude that nobody refers to Elastic Beanstalk as "EBT" in the wild.  I recommend using "EB" to avoid confusion, as that's what it's always abbreviated to on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Since I have custom `wp-config.php` committed to the repo (it reads keys and passwords from environment variables, no Booo please), I can add a temporary workaround

```
if (function_exists('apache_request_headers')) {
  $all_headers = apache_request_headers();
  $_SERVER['HTTP_X_WP_NONCE'] = $all_headers['HTTP_X_WP_NONCE'];
}
```